# Асинхронная загрузка файла на сервер с параметрами

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте пишу на net framework 4.0, вот уже второй день не могу решать эту проблему, как же выслать файл на сервер, вместе с параметрами, я уже пробовал webrequest и у меня там проблема была с Tls соединением, писало, что невозможно установить безопасное соединение с сервером. И тут я стал гуглить и нашел как бы решение:

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Но тут опять облом, в net framework недоступно SecurityProtocolType.Tls11.
Далее я использовал HttpWebRequest, но там я так и не понял как использовать асинхронно отправку файла.
Теперь, что на счет httpclien, он не доступен в framework 4.0, но я нашел библиотеку там где она работала, однако я не смог метод сделать асинхронным т.к так требуется await, а у framework 4.0 проблемы с асинхронностью.
Вообщем такие дела, если кто нибудь нашел решение, поделитесь пожалуйста, завтра 3-ий день пойдет

Comment: Сочувствую вам, 4 .NET это самое ужасное, что можно придумать для современного разработчика. Ну а так, гугл советует `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType) 3072;`

Comment: Вам нужно поддерживать Windows XP чтоли?

Comment: Думаю стоит копать в направление "Асинхронная модель на основе событий (EAP)". Устаревший шаблон асинхрощины, в вашем случае может помочь.